# Connection Refused from AWS instance even after changing Inbound Rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, ip

I know, that when someone says that he gets a `Connection Refuse Error` trying to connect to AWS, the first is that he usually didn't change the Inbound Rules in the Security Group.

Well, I installed Elasticsearch in an Instance, and that's why I need to have the port 9200 free, at least from my office IP.

I did it, as it can be sawed here: [image: here]

Where the port 9200 should be open for the ES (Elastic Search) Security Group, which is the Security Group of the Instance. 
`88.217.142.163` is the IP of my Office and `172.31.0.0/16` are the private IPs of AWS.

But when I try this: 
`curl -XGET '35.156.142.21:9200'`, which is the instance IP, I get this:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.156.142.21 port 9200: Connection refused

I'm sure that `88.217.142.163` is my IP.

I tried this `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'` inside the instance via `ssh`(BTW, ssh works perfectly) and I get this:

```
{
  "name" : "HH0nrrR",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "W1BMrQ_OTnG4N48y6zhqcw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.3.0",
    "build_hash" : "3adb13b",
    "build_date" : "2017-03-23T03:31:50.652Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

So, quite good. The only problem is with the 9200 port from my office.

I don't know if I have to wait more time, I waited like 2 hours or so, and I still get the connection refused error.

Maybe someone had the same error.

Comment: Is the Elasticsearch server only listening to connections from localhost? Is the port open in the firewall software on the server?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe is an issue with Elastic Search. How could I see it?

Comment: Look here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html note where it says *"Elasticsearch binds to localhost only by default"*.

Comment: Do you mean ```ufw ``` as firewall ? It's not enabled if it's

Comment: Yeah! thanks The problem was with Elastic Search I just changed the network.host and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to change the `elasticsearch.yml` in `/etc/elasticsearch` and there as here says:

[doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html)

The `network.host` change. By default has Elasticsearch just the localhost.

Many thanks to Mark B for the Idea!